# Codeigniter - get all users session data

Tags: php, session, codeigniter-3, session-variables

I need to get all sessions data and take some actions upon them, is there any possible way to get them, I found how to solve it in php but codeigniter use's it own custom sessions library.

Native php

`$_SESSION`

How can I do it in codeigniter

Comment: This will help you `$this->session->all_userdata();`. Load session library before this snippet.

Comment: is there any specific data that you want to get that is not available in the codeigniter session class?

Comment: @RahilWazir $this->session->all_userdata(); does not help because it has only single array for each of users, what I am try to do 
e.x Let say i have 2 users logged in into my sistem user A & B and my issue is how do I get session datas of user B from user A. 
Am i clear enough and thanks for your help

Comment: @sabri You can create a column `status` in your user table with default value of `0` and when user logged in execute query and change `status` value to `1`. Query all users whos status is `1` and you will get the data from users whos login. Remember set it back to `0` after logout.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To get all session data you can use `$this->session->all_userdata();`

To print all your session variable use this line anywhere in your code :

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($this->session->all_userdata());exit;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use db session.
So data will be stored to the database.
See [Saving Session Data to a Database](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

If you have no database support just use cookie and get the data with

```
$username = 'John Doe';
$this->session->set_userdata('username',$username);
$var = $this->session->userdata;
echo $var['username'];
```

Comment: Yes this would be an solution but in my case I can not use db :) +1

Comment: You can use session stored in cookkie from the codeigniter config file.

Answer (score 1):

To get all users session data.First we need to initialize the Session class manually in our controller constructor use following code.

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

Then we use following code.

```
$this->session->all_userdata();
```

Above function return an associative array like the following.

```
Array
( [session_id] => 4a5b5dca45708ab1a84364eeb455j007 [ip_address] => 127.0.0.1 [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_7; [last_activity] => 1102132923
)
```

For complete Ci Session tutorial. Please referrer following [link](http://www.tutsway.com/codeigniter-session.php)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see *everything* the way I've done it is to cast `$this->session` as array then `print_r` it.

```
        $this->load->library('session');
        echo "<pre>". print_r((array)$this->session, true) ."</pre>";
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to do this in PHP why not implement that, and not use the codeigniter session class?  my experience is that the CI session class breaks pretty badly with ajax calls and proxy servers, so it is best avoided.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->session->userdata('data')->username
```

Comment: fetch data from datas in codeigniter session, it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

To Print All Session Data

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($this->session);
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed similar thing to view all active sessions

```
var_dump($this->session->all_userdata());
```

above code did the job. For details go to the below link

https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html#CI_Session::all_userdata